# Browse websites through VPN

Tags: vpn, debian-jessie

I've already configured a VPN server on Debian 8 using [this script](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn). It uses wlan0 interface.
I've also successfully connected with my Windows 10 client to the server.

What I've been trying to do is to redirect internet traffic from the client to the VPN server, to browse internet as if I was in the server's network. I don't need to access resources of this last network.
Both server and client are behind a NAT router.

Windows says that I'm connected to the VPN server, but there's no internet connection. In fact, when I try to browse any site the browser says it can't.

Please, say if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your question is wrong a little bit.  The internet always provides vpn server while the clients connect to it. If you want the Internet operates on Windows 10 with Debian, you should start the server on Windows.
On the whole, you should try to use ordinary vpn services with simple installation  https://www.bestvpnrating.com/vpnrating It can help you to avoid many problems concerning installation and usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. I wanted to set up a personal vpn server, in order to not to relay on a third part service provider. It's just for personal use